# Graphing polynomials

Tags: python, numpy, graph

With some help I have produced the following code. Below are some of the desired outputs for given inputs. However I am having some trouble completing the last task of this code. Looking for some help with this, any guidance or help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

[image]

```
flops = 0

def add(x1, x2):
    global flops
    flops += 1
    return x1 + x2

def multiply(x1, x2):
    global flops
    flops += 1
    return x1 * x2

def poly_horner(A, x):
    global flops
    flops = 0
    p = A[-1]
    i = len(A) - 2
    while i >= 0:
        p = add(multiply(p, x), A[i])
        i -= 1
    return p

def poly_naive(A, x):
    global flops
    p = 0
    flops = 0
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        xp = 1
        for _ in range(i):
            xp = multiply(xp, x)
            p = add(p, multiply(xp, a))
    return p
```

Given the following inputs, I got the following outputs:

```
poly_horner([1,2,3,4,5], 2)
129
print(flops)
8
poly_naive([1,2,3,4,5, 2])
129
print(flops)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
20
np.polyval([5,4,3,2,1], 2)
129
```

Comment: What specific trouble are you having completing the last task?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
We need something more specific than "I'm having trouble", especially since "plotting" is very well covered in on-line tutorials and examples.

Comment: @martineau I am not quite sure how to complete this part of the question

Comment: @Prune thanks, ill keep that in mind

Comment: user123: That's still overly vague. Perhaps downloading / installing something like [matplotlib](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/) would help (assuming you don't already have it and that's what you mean about being unsure about how to complete task).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to create a figure, though your question is quite vague...but I have a few minutes to kill while my code runs.  Anyway, it seems you MIGHT be having difficulty plotting.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

x = np.arange(10)
y = x * np.pi

# you can calculate a line of best fit (lobf) using numpy's polyfit function
lobf1 = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)  # first degree polynomial
lobf2 = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)  # second degree polynomial
lobf3 = np.polyfit(x, y, 3)  # third degree polynomial

# you can now use the lines of best fit to calculate the 
# value anywhere within the domain using numpy's polyval function
# FIRST, create a figure and a plotting axis within the fig
fig = pl.figure(figsize=(3.25, 2.5))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)

# now use polyval to calculate your y-values at every x
x = np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
ax0.plot(x, np.polyval(lobf1, x), 'k')
ax0.plot(x, np.polyval(lobf2, x), 'b')
ax0.plot(x, np.polyval(lobf3, x), 'r')

# add a legend for niceness
ax0.legend(('Degree 1', 'Degree 2', 'Degree 3'), fontsize=8, loc=2)

# you can label the axes whatever you like
ax0.set_ylabel('My y-label', fontsize=8)
ax0.set_xlabel('My x-label', fontsize=8)

# you can show the figure on your screen
fig.show()

# and you can save the figure to your computer in different formats
# specifying bbox_inches='tight' helps eliminate unnecessary whitespace around
# the axis when saving...it just looks better this way.
pl.savefig('figName.png', dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight')
pl.savefig('figName.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')

# don't forget to close the figure
pl.close('all')
```

Comment: so I just need to add this to my code to make it run?

Comment: also I need to use plt.show() instead of fig.show() to make my code run!

Comment: or is this just a general way to plot? not actually answering my original post

Comment: Your original post is ambiguous to the degree that it cannot be answered.  I took a chance that you might need help creating your figures...looks like I wasted my time.

Comment: no it helped! I will look over it to learn how to create figures